# Ставится ли запятая: "Во исполнение...(,) направляю...", "Учитывая...(,) приказываю..."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Ставится ли запятая перед словами "направляю", "приказываю", "утверждаю"...
Например: "Во исполнение требований письма направляю сведения согласно представленной формы" или "...учитывая вышесказанное, приказываю..."

Answer (score 2):

В первом предложении "во исполнение...направляю" никаких запятых не надо. Во втором предложении есть деепричастный оборот "учитывая вышесказанное", который следует выделить запятой. Обратите внимание на ошибку в Вашем тексте: "направляю сведения согласно (чему?) представленной формЕ"